# Почему в лямбда выражении не получается поставить фигурные скобки?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть работающий код:

```
bExchColumn.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());
```

При попытке вставить фигурные скобки в лямбда-выражение ...

```
bExchColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {EditCell.createStringEditCell();});
```

eclipse ругается:

> The method `setCellFactory(CallBack<TableColumn<Bread,String>,TableCell<Bread,String>>)`
>   in the type `TableColumn<Bread,String>` is not applicable for the
>   arguments `((<no type> column) -> {})`"

В чем ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: `return` добавьте между `{` и `EditCell`

Answer (score 5):

Цитаты из [урока Oracle по лямбдам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (расставил акценты и перевёл).

В разделе "из чего состоит лямбда":

> A body, which consists of a **single expression** or a **statement block**.
>
> Тело, состоящее из **единственного выражения** или **блока инструкций**.

Обращаю внимание, что "блок инструкций" это набор инструкций в `{}`. Далее:

> If you specify a single expression, then the Java runtime evaluates the expression and then returns its value. **Alternatively, you can use a `return` statement**
>
> Если указать единственное выражение, рантайм Java вычислит это выражение и вернёт его значение. **Или же можно использовать инструкцию `return`**

Посему, вот два равноценных примера:

```
p -> выражение
p -> { return выражение; }
```

Вы же написали `p -> { выражение; }`, которое им **не эквивалентно** и **ничего не возвращает**.

Answer (score 2):

До полноценной лямбды не хватает `return`:

```
{return EditCell.createStringEditCell();}
```

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от комментария @Nofate?

Comment: @Denis Тем, что 1) я его не заметил(соответственно и вопрошающий мог не заметить), 2) все же у меня полноценный кусок кода. 3) я СПЕЦИАЛЬНО не оборачивал ответ в код, что бы слово return можно было выделить жирным - это касаемо вашей правки.

Comment: 1. сложно не заметить, 2. ваш полноценный кусок кода по прежнему не отличается от комментария @Nofate, 3. ок, можете исправить обратно или добавить словами.

Comment: @Denis ну я же смог :)

Answer (score 1):

Метод `bExchColumn.setCellFactory()` ожидает какой-то аргумент, который должно вернуть лямбда-выражение. В вашем работающем варианте в качестве аргумента используется значение, возвращенное методом `EditCell.createStringEditCell()` (потому что лямбда состоит из него одного), а во втором варианте этот метод - часть тела лямбда-выражения, а его результат не возвращается из лямбды, а игнорируется (не присваивается ничему и не возвращается).